# Feasibility of Kubernetes resource YAML files inside the SVN code repository

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I am trying to implement the CI/CD pipeline using docker , Jenkins and Kubernetes. And I am storing Jenkinsfile inside my SVN code repository. Previously when I implemented pipeline using Kubernetes helm chart , I was keeping helm chart inside my SVN code only,

Here My implementation style changed and I am not using any helm chart. Instead of that I am using plane YAML files for my Kubernetes deployments and services. Here my confusion is that Can I keep all the Kubernetes resources YAML files inside my code repository like how I implemented the helm chart?

Can anyone clear my confusion about feasibility of keeping Kubernetes resources YAML files inside my code repository please?

Comment: Of course you can! Why shouldn't you?

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course you can keep them along with your application source code like you keep the build definition as Jenkinsfile.

You might want to use Jenkins to automatically deploy your build result to a (testing) kubernetes cluster as well.

Make sure to check out kustomize as well: https://kustomize.io/